# Retrieving attribute from DOM via external function, using promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am somewhat new to protractor/jasmine and most especially javascript, for writing front end test automation.
I have an object in the DOM that I am trying to retrieve and evaluate. It is essentially a column height value. I need to eval this in a function in a separate class from my test script.

The test script call looks like this (the 'selector' is predefined and valid):

```
colHeight = lib.getColumnHeight(selector);  
console.log(colHeight);
```

The html DOM looks like this:

```
class="bar" fill-opacity="0.000001" x="123.02739726027396" width="6" height="10.8" y="15.8"
```

I've set up the function but think I'm tripping up on the promise concept; I keep getting a return of *undefined*. 
What I want is to simply return the value of *height*.
Here's a look at my function:

```
this.getColumnHeight = function(selector) {

var tmpSelector = element(by.css(selector));

  var found = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var look = function() {
      tmpSelector.getAttribute("height").then(function(text) { 
        var h = text;
        console.log("h = " + h);
        return h; 
      })
    }
  var value = look();
  return value;
  })
}
```

The line:

```
console.log("h = " + h);
```

Correctly returns the value.
I'm not sure how to get 'h' out of the look() function and returned into my original test script.
Where am I falling down? Any pointers much appreciated.

**EDIT (5/9/16):**

Not clear on understanding how to pass the value back out into my test script, from the then() block. My current code returns a { pending } for the promise.
Thanks much in advance.

Call (tests.js):

```
colHeight = lib.getColumnHeight(selector);
console.log(colHeight);
```

Function (lib.js):

```
this.getColumnHeight = function(selector) {
    var tmpSelector = element(by.css(selector));

    return new Promise(
        function(resolve,reject) {
        var height = 0;
        setTimeout( function(){  resolve(height);  }, 2000 );
    })

    tmpSelector.getAttribute("height").then( function(valueFromResolve) {
    A = valueFromResolve;
    console.log(A);
    return A;
    })
}
```

Comment: It's not clear why you need to use a promise.

Comment: I'm very open to suggestions. The getAttribute function is promise based. If there is a better solution, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

By your comment it seems that getAttribue is a promise, and you want to get the height value from the promise.

```
//Pretend getAttribute function
function getAttribute(selector) {

  return new Promise( function(resolve,reject) {

    var height = 114.5;

    setTimeout( function(){  resolve(height);  }, 1000 );
    //After 1 second resolve promise and pass height to .then() function
  })
}

var A = "I get printed before .then()"

getAttribute("#myTable").then( function(valueFromResolve) {
   A = valueFromResolve;
   console.log(A);
})
console.log(A); //This will run before console.log(A) inside .then()
                // even if there is no time delay in setTimeout()
```

Any function inside a `.then()` is put on hold until all the other synchronous code is run.

In your code, `return h` is going to return after `return value`. At `return value`'s time of execution, h *is* undefined.

`console.log("h = " + h);` works because it's being called within the `.then()` function, at a time where var `var h = text` has been run (after all the synchronous code has been run).

**Edit**: Actually not after *all* the synchronous code has been run, but until the function stack is empty. The function `look` will be occupying the stack and anything inside `.then()` will wait for the stack to be empty.

The point is really just to remember that code inside `.then()` is executed when the Promise resolves (or is rejected) and not by its order from top-to-bottom like we're used to.

Comment: Thanks, john.abraham. I’m still having problems understanding how to pass the value back out into my test script, from the then() block. I edited my above post to show my current code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @bmagstadt Any code that you want to be aware of your new value has to be called from inside .then() or from a .then() further down the promise chain. Code that runs before .then() will not be aware of what .then() returns.